# Navicat mySQL: Saving default view of a table

Tags: mysql, navicat

Simple question but I'll be damned if I can figure it out.  I use Navicat for Mysql 10.1.8 and I open a specific table probably 20 times a day, and I always have to resort it by the index to show the newest records first.  This only take a couple of seconds, but it's a step I've done every day for the last 4 years and I was hoping to learn how to set the default open view.

Thanks for your time and consideration!

Comment: I create / save / re-use my queries saved in the queries folder.

Comment: @Eric:  Yeah, I guess that would work.  Although I have a ton of saved queries already, hate to clutter it up any more.  Thanks for the idea thought!

Comment: Remember that when you select that folder and start typing, the non relevant queries will disappear :)

Comment: @Eric:  That's a great tip, I didnt know that.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer to this question that does not involve creating/saving queries for each table, as I would like to set this sorting by default. In other software this is a global setting called something like "Sort tables by numeric primary key". Navicat does not seem to have this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view of the table and use that to see and update the records
Just create a view as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY index DESC
```